# Combine grep with flags and pipe operator to filter a file

Tags: grep, pipe

I have a file (smartphones) which contains different smartphones in it:

Brand: Apple
Type: iPhone 7
Color: Silver
Years: 2

Brand: Apple
Type: iPhone 7
Color: Gold
Years: 3

Brand: Apple
Type: iPhone 8
Color: Silver
Years: 1

Brand: Apple
Type: iPhone 7
Color: Silver
Years: 1

How can I search, using multiple keywords, the smartphone that I am looking for if I would like to combine grep with flags and the pipe operator to filter the research?

The result I am looking for should look something like this:

Brand: Apple
Type: iPhone 7
Color: Silver
Years: 1

I tried different ways, also the -e flag, but what I am getting is different lines with all the results matching my keywords and not just only one smartphone which match all my keywords.

Answer (score 0):

`cat <your_file_name_here> | grep 'Brand: Apple' | grep 'Type: iPhone 7'`

Will get all Apple iPhone 7's

You can add `| grep 'Color: Silver'` to get all Silver iPhone 7s.

Note that this assumes there is always a `key: value` - if there could be different amounts of whitespace etc then you;d need to do something more clever.

Comment: When I do it, it doesn't give me any ouputs

Comment: Start with something simpler then `cat yourfile | grep 'Brand'` - that should get every line right? so then try `cat yourfile | grep 'Brand' | grep 'Apple'` That should get you less lines right? so add on more `| grep 'Gold'` etc

Comment: If I do cat file | grep "Apple" - it gives me this: 
Brand: Apple
Brand: Apple
Brand: Apple

If I add a second keyword, then it doesn't give me any output at all.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I had to use flags to show me the lines before and after my keywords:

grep Apple myfile -A2 | grep iPhone -C1 | 1 -B2

Where A2 stays for - show me the next two lines after my keyword, C1 stays for - show me the line before and the line after my keyword and -B2 stays for show me the 2 lines before my keyword.